# Percolation in Java - data structure used

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I am following [Sedgewick's course](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/24percolation/) on algorithms and am having problems understanding the data structure used when solving the percolation problem in Java.

What I've figured out on my own (without looking at [others' solutions](https://github.com/ShuaiW/Java/blob/master/algorithms/percolation/Percolation.java)) is that a boolean `NxN` array will be used for the grid (***true/false*** denotes ***open/closed*** field). However, when using a virtual top and bottom, the solution defines them as:

```
bottom = N * N + 1;  //virtual bottom
private int top = 0; //virtual top
```

and a weighted UnionFind object as:

```
uf = new WeightedQuickUnionUF(N * N + 2);
```

Could anyone explain why it is: **N * N + 2**?

Code for WeightedQuickUnion:

```
public WeightedQuickUnionUF(int n) {
    count = n;
    parent = new int[n];
    size = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        parent[i] = i;
        size[i] = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey! It would be a nice thing to not make your question dependent on the link.

Comment: @Quant you have to show code for `WeightedQuickUnionUF` class I suppose.

Comment: It's a bit long, so I hope it's okay putting up a link: https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/15uf/WeightedQuickUnionUF.java.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while so I'm sure you have figured it out. It's `N*N +2` because there're N*N grids in total for a NxN square, and +2 for 2 virtual sites.